# stk11xx driver on raspberry-pi installation error

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have an error in my instalation in my raspberry-pi 3, it's a driver for a web-cam

I took the driver on this page:
https://github.com/hbars/stk11xx-driver
and the manual for this instalation is here:
https://github.com/hbars/stk11xx-driver/blob/master/INSTALL

it's on this line:

```
 make -f Makefile.standalone driver
```

error:

```
 make -f Makefile.standalone driver
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.66-v7+/build SUBDIRS=/home/pi/stk11xx-2.1.0 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.66-v7+'
  CC [M]  /home/pi/stk11xx-2.1.0/stk11xx-usb.o
/home/pi/stk11xx-2.1.0/stk11xx-usb.c: In function 'usb_stk11xx_probe':
/home/pi/stk11xx-2.1.0/stk11xx-usb.c:793:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'init_MUTEX' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_MUTEX(&dev->mutex);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:303: recipe for target '/home/pi/stk11xx-2.1.0/stk11xx-usb.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/stk11xx-2.1.0/stk11xx-usb.o] Error 1
Makefile:1519: recipe for target '_module_/home/pi/stk11xx-2.1.0' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/pi/stk11xx-2.1.0] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.66-v7+'
Makefile.standalone:13: recipe for target 'driver' failed
make: *** [driver] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry this is not the good error it's the one:

```
 make -C /lib/modules/4.19.66-v7+/build SUBDIRS=/home/pi/stk11xx-driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.66-v7+'
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/pi/stk11xx-driver/.tmp_versions': Permission denied
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/pi/stk11xx-driver/modules.order: Permission denied
scripts/Makefile.build:462: recipe for target '/home/pi/stk11xx-driver/modules.order' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/stk11xx-driver/modules.order] Error 2
Makefile:1519: recipe for target '_module_/home/pi/stk11xx-driver' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/pi/stk11xx-driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.66-v7+'
Makefile.standalone:13: recipe for target 'driver' failed
make: *** [driver] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem I had to put `sudo` in front of `make -f Makefile.standalone driver`
but I have an other error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.66-v7+/build SUBDIRS= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.66-v7+'
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl', needed by 'arch/arm/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd-common.h'.  Stop.
arch/arm/Makefile:319: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.66-v7+'
Makefile.standalone:13: recipe for target 'driver' failed
make: *** [driver] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have resolved my problem, replacing all `PWD` whith `shell pwd` in Makefile.standalonee